# Is the Spoilers Usage allowed?

Tags: discussion

Shall the use of Spoilers be allowed when asking a question?

> I mean this kind of spoilers. [This is spam!!. Click here to get 1 million dollars.](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/8243/is-the-spoilers-usage-allowed?noredirect=1#comment14844_8243)

[aesthetics](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/aesthetics) [spoilers](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/spoilers) [community](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/community) [root-user](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/root-user)

Comment: Why not? What question in particular are you talking about? I don't see why we would need to use them though..

Comment: @Seth I just find it tricky and it could be taked to make spam, don't you think?

Comment: I've never even seen one used on this site, so I don't consider it an issue.

Comment: @Seth You are probably rigth.

Comment: and now you have spam in there, flagged accordingly

Comment: @Mateo Yeah, that is what I mean! (and actually it is not spam, is a link to this same question, just trying to prove my point). I wouldn't spam on meta, I think no one would.

Comment: @Seth Can you see it now?

Comment: Yes I can see it, but I'm still not worried.

Answer (score 5):

It's not disallowed but it's a feature built for a specific purpose. To hide plot spoilers.

I don't see how that'll apply to us but I can't say it never will. Just don't use it for other things. Your example is a good example of illegitimate use. That should be edited out (or if it's actually spam, just plain flagged up as spam).